# Java EE Authentication Basic And Form

Tags: rest, jdbc, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I have developed an web application with jdbc and form based authentication. The user can login through jsf-pages and everything works fine.

Now i want to add an RESTful webservice with basic authentication but i only can have form based authentication. How can i achieve two authentication modes at a time? (Form-based for JSF and Basic for REST)